# Override init in subclassed UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to ovrride `init(frame: CGRect)` in a subclassed UITableViewCell.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
   super.init(frame: CGRect)
}
```

But this throws an error: `Initializer does not ovrride a designated initializer from its super class`, I did something wrong?

Comment: Just a small comment here, when you call super.init you should pass in the frame instead of calling an empty init. The super init call should look like this super.init(frame: frame)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For an `UITableViewCell`, you should be overriding this one:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html).

If you would like to be able to vary cells' frame, you should look into delegate methods like:

- `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)` for row height
- `tableView(_:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:)` for row indent

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) for `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I override this because I wanna use `frame` in `init(frame: CGRect)` do something. Is there any other way can use the cell's `frame`?

Comment: What do you need exactly?

Comment: I wanna create some width equal bottons with frame.width

Comment: I am guessing this is because you are getting an incorrect value for your `frame.width` in the initializer? I recommend using `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width` or the width of your `tableView`

Comment: Not yet. Cell's width isn't constant.

Comment: @ZeroChow not sure what you mean

Comment: Sorry for that !  Put it another way, I wanna create some height equal bottons with frame.height.

Comment: is it width or height then? are your rows of a custom height? do they vary in sizes?

Comment: height. It vary in sizes.

Comment: you could have an extra method on your `UITableViewCell` subclass that you call after `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and send `height` as a parameter. you would set your button up in there.

Answer (score 0):

`init(frame: CGRect)` is not an initializer of the superclass UITableViewCell. You need to override `init(coder: aDecoder)` or `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UITableViewCell has only two initializers

```
public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `init(frame: CGRect)`, use `UICollectionViewCell`. And set the size of your cell with `CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)`. For example,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
}
```

It looks like tableViewCell and you also can use `init(frame: CGRect)`.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:
if you need to directly change the height of the cell,you can use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
  }
```

Case 2:
If you need to subclass a cell,go to that cell class and override the reuseidentifier

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
 let hrt = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    hrt.isActive = true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the `init` functions you need to override in your child `[UITableView][1]`

```
override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
    //When you manually initializing a table
    super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    //From xib or storyboard
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```